# How to configure thank you page in Google Analytics with REGEX?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I would like to track in Google Analytics the below thank you page with a REGEX. The below thank you page will vary depending of the title of the file downloaded (title-content). Hence, what kind of regex do I need in order to count the conversion regardless of the title of the file to be downloaded?

/en/media/download/title-content/thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess, you're trying to *match* the path you listed.

Something like this might work:

`^/en/media/download/[^/]+/thanks$`

Here I'm using `[^/]+` instead of `.+` because we want to match only characters which are not the slash, since I'm assuming `^/en/media/download/blah-blah/not/thanks$` should not match.

It kind of depends what language you're going for, though. This answer could vary depending whether you are doing this in an Apache config file, a PHP script, Javascript, or something else.

Also, the "anchors" (^ and $) force the match to start at the start of the string, and to end at the end, so `foo/en/media/download/bar/thanks/baz` won't match. Remove either or both as appropriate.

Also, depending on your regex engine, the `/` characters may need to be escaped, replacing each one with `\/` instead (apparently not needed for Google Analytics!)

Also, depending on your regex engine, you might need to put a character at the beginning and end of the regex, and you might need to quote it. For example, in PHP you'd use something like: `if (preg_match('#^/en/media/download/[^/]+/thanks$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { /* do stuff here. */}` (also apparently not needed for Google Analytics!)

---

Thanks to a comment by @kbelder, you might want to consider something like this, if you're comparing against the whole request URI:

`^/en/media/download/[^/]+/thanks/?([#?].*)?$`

- /? - An optional trailing slash.
- [#?] - A hash or questionmark.
- .* - Any number of extra characters.
- ([#?].*)? - Optional GET parameters or anchor id.

This would mean it'd match:

- `/en/media/download/blah/thanks/?name=fred`
- `/en/media/download/blah/thanks#credits`

but not:

- `/en/media/download/blah/thanks/name/fred`
- `/en/media/download/blah/thanks/credits`

Comment: I'm familiar with regex matching in Google Analytics, and I think your code should work fine.  It doesn't need escaping for "/".  I might not include the "$" for end of string, because URLs sometimes have parameters added that you'd want to ignore for this case.

Comment: Thank you, @kbelder! I could claim I was just unsure what language or regex engine Google analytics uses, but I must be honest and admit that I somehow completely missed the google analytics tag... and in the title... and in the question. I'll just go shamefully crawl under this convenient rock, now...